# Draw Line figure in Windows form with all the sides variable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, line

I know how to draw rectangle, line and ovals on windows form but I am not sure how to draw this type of [........figure........](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgl0O.jpg)
in windows form. I want all three sides to be variable so I can change its size and also the thickness of line should be variable.
I can draw line like this

```
    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0))
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 20, 10, 300, 100)
```

but how do I manage to draw the above shown picture?
Can I group these lines showhow?
Any help will be highly appreciated

Cheers
Mak

Comment: Consult [System.Drawing.DrawLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7ewkcdb3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim pen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0))
' Create array of points that define lines to draw.
Dim points As Point() = {New Point(10, 100), New Point(10, 10), New Point(100, 10), New Point(100, 100)}
'Draw lines to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pen, points)
```